# Basic submit button - save text

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new and want to learn something about the submit button. I'm working on a very small program. You can write some names and then I want to save their values and use them in my Javascript code.

What I exactly want is call all of the textboxes so I can use the value (the names) in my Javascript.

```
    <form name="input" action="#" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
                <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
                <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
                <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
                <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
                <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
                <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
                <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
                <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
                <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>

    <input type='submit' >
```

**Edit:** So the next question is just how do I make a button that will run the javascript? When the user finished type names, he can press the button and then will the javascript run and stack the 'txt' values in an input array? I know how to make the javascript, but the button is the problem. How do I make that?

Comment: see my update in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all `input` values, there is a little change with your `html`

```
<input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
<input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
<input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
<input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
<input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
<input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
<input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
<input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
<input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
<input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="Calculate()" />
```

Then you can use `javascript` like this

```
function Calculate(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByName("txt");
    for(i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)
    {
       alert(inputs[i].value);
    }
}
```

[getElementsByName() Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)

With `jquery`

```
function Calculate(){  
    $("input[name=txt]").each(function(){
         alert($(this).val());
    });
}
```

Comment: So all of the values will be stacked in a 'inputs' array? (with the html-javascript part)

Comment: Well, I'm just wondering, if the user just types in name after name, it wouldn't work the right way. Cause I want a button as the user can press, so the program know when the user is done.

EDIT: So when the user press the button, then the Javascript will begin running. How can I make that?

Comment: @user1994248 you can add `button` to your form and so when the user click after entering names bind it to a function. See the updated answer

Comment: @user1994248 i already updated, check for `Calculate` function and `<input type="button" />` in the answer

Comment: Great, the very last thing is, where should I call my Javascript document? Should I just write it directly in the html file or log it like  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> ? And then where?

Comment: just add `<script>` tag in the head section of the `html` page with the `Calculate()` function in it.

Answer (score 0):

better use jquery to retrieve the values which is easier and simpler. http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

```
<form name="input" action="#" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="1" value="Insert name"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="2" value="Insert name"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="3" value="Insert name"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="4" value="Insert name"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="5" value="Insert name"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="6" value="Insert name"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="7" value="Insert name"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="8" value="Insert name"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="9" value="Insert name"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="10" value="Insert name"><br/>
        </td>
</tr>
```

```
<input type='submit' >

<script>
 var one = $('input[name=1]').val();
 var two = $('input[name=2]').val();
 var three= $('input[name=3]').val();
 var four = $('input[name=4]').val();
 ..
 //use one,two,three according to your wish
</script>
```

or even simpler(change the `name=1,2..` to `name=txt`):

```
$('input[name=txt]').each(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

`$('input[name=txt]')` < -- this part will become an array of values from all inputs. `each` will iterate over them.

EDIT: your button should be like this:

```
<input type="button" id="submitme" value="Submit"/>
```

and you will call your js function like this:

```
$('#submitme').click(function(){
   $('input[name=txt]').each(function() {
     alert($(this).val());
   });      
});
```

by the way: i just assumed that you dont want to submit the form first, but just get the values into array.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use JQuery.

Like This

```
 <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
 <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
 <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
 <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
 <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
 <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
 <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
 <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
 <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
 <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
```

Code:

```
 $('input[name="txt"]').each(function(index, element) {
       alert(element.value);         
 });
```